# Picasso Out of Memory Error?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, out-of-memory, picasso

For loading images into a listview (in my case 25 kb "profile" pictures) i bound picasso yesterday so the images are loaded faster and cached to disk. but since then i'm constantly get out of memory error even if i dont open the activity where the images are loaded. 
could it be cache isn't cleared so my app cannot handle any server requests anymore? did anybody face this problem too? or am i basically doing something wrong?

Genreally my app starts by loading a google map were markers are placed on specific places given by JSON request. if i slide to another place to load these markers, the out of memory error occurs when trying to load the JSON from Server. Never happened before, only since I included picasso library into my app.

here is my listitem for the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/friends_image"
    />

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/friends_image"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_friends_textview" />

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
/>
```

Comment: Does your images have this attribute? : `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` also tried to `.fit().centerCrop()`

Comment: Add it on all of your imageviews and test it agian and let me know if it throws outofmemory

Comment: still the same error. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **ScaleType**

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

Comment: so shall i do both, add scaleType and android:adjustViewBounds="true"?

Answer (score 0):

Adding AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<application
             ....
             ....
             android:largeHeap="true"

 </application>
```

Comment: on the net many people say this is not the solution as it does not really solve the problem in the long run...?

Comment: yeah, it does not solve problem instead makes problem for other running app, it tells system to app need more memory and hence system gets memory by killing other background app